# Image Slider nothing happens

Tags: javascript, html, css

so i'm planning to put a slider on my page but the codes are not working i already double checked it on my source and all of my codes are correct can you help me how can i make my slider work thank you very much please reply a soon as possible.

my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <title>SLIDER</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="draft3.css">
            <!--HEADER-->
<header>
    <div class="header">
</header>
<body>
            <!--NAVIGATION-->
<div class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="draft3.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="draft4.html">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Feedback</a></li>
            <li><a href="Reg.html">Register</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
            <!--Gallery-->
<div id="slider">
    <figure>
        <img src="g1.jpg">
        <img src="g2.jpg">
        <img src="g3.jpg">
        <img src="g4.jpg">
    </figure>
</div>
</body>
```

THIS IS MY CSS

```
*{
   Padding:0px;
   margin:0px;
}
body{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    font-family:Sans-serif;
}
.header{
    background-image:url(head.jpg);
    height: 250px;
    width:100%;
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center;
}
.nav{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color:#1a0e34;
    text-align:Center;
}
.nav ul{
    list-style-type:none;
    line-height:50px;
}
.nav ul li{
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:40px;
}
.nav ul li a{
    color:#f8992d;
    background-color:transparent;
    border:2px solid #f8992d;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size:20px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.nav ul li a:hover{
    color:#1a0e34;
    background-color:#f8992d;
}
/*End of Nav and Header*/
#slider{
    overflow: hidden;
}
#slider figure{
    position: relative;
    width: 500%;
    margin: 0;
    left:0;
}
#slider figure img{
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: "how can i make my slider work" ... what slider? there is just a bunch of html image tags which are not animated at all?!

Comment: all of them are not animated.

Comment: Your Question is unclear. You ask "how can i make my slider work", but you dont show us any code of "your slider" ... just css code that is non-essential for this problem and some image-tags bundled in a div?!?

Comment: Is there any JS code you have used and can share with us?

Comment: @AKNair hi i didn't use a JS in here all i need to make this Slider work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested and works:(Replace your images with the sample ones)

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>SLIDER</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="draft3.css">
            <!--HEADER-->
<header>
    <div class="header"></div>
</header>
<style>
*{
   Padding:0px;
   margin:0px;
}
body{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    font-family:Sans-serif;
}
.header{
    background-image:url(head.jpg);
    height: 250px;
    width:100%;
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center;
}
.nav{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color:#1a0e34;
    text-align:Center;
}
.nav ul{
    list-style-type:none;
    line-height:50px;
}
.nav ul li{
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:40px;
}
.nav ul li a{
    color:#f8992d;
    background-color:transparent;
    border:2px solid #f8992d;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size:20px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.nav ul li a:hover{
    color:#1a0e34;
    background-color:#f8992d;
}
/*End of Nav and Header*/
#slider{
    overflow: hidden;
}
#slider figure{
    position: relative;
    width: 500%;
    margin: 0;
    left:0;
}
#slider figure img{
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
            <!--NAVIGATION-->
<div class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="draft3.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="draft4.html">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Feedback</a></li>
            <li><a href="Reg.html">Register</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
            <!--Gallery-->
<div id="slider">
    <figure>
        <img class="mySlides" src="1.jpg"/>
        <img class="mySlides" src="2.jpg"/>
        <img class="mySlides" src="3.jpg"/>
        <img class="mySlides" src="4.jpg"/>
        <img class="mySlides" src="5.jpg"/>

    </figure>
</div>
<script>
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  //var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
  slideIndex = 1
  }    
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  setTimeout(showSlides, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hi thank you but can you explain the function you used? 
function showSlides() {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  //var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
  slideIndex = 1
  }    
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  setTimeout(showSlides, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
</script>

Comment: This function is used to display an automatic slideshow. It will display and hide the slider images i.e collection of all elements in the document with the specified class name 'myslides'. For every 2 second it will hide previous image and then simply display next one using css and js. When finished again initiating with starting index.